# Why does the sequence $\{p_n\}$ converge to $q$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Theorem 5. The closure of a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is the set of all limits of converging sequences of points from $S$.
>
> proof. Let $\{p_n\}$ be a sequence of poins in $S$, with $\lim p_n = p$. We shall first show that $p$ belongs to the closure of $S$. This is certainly true if $p$ is either in $S$ or in the boundary of $S$. Could $p$ be exterior to $S$? If so, then there would be a small neighborhood $U$ about $p$ such that $U$ contains no points of $S$. In particular, $U$ contains none of the points $p_n$, contradicting the fact that ${p_n}$ converges to $p$.Hence, $p$ lies in the closure of $S$.
>
> To complete the proof, we must show that every point the closure of $S$ can be the limit of a converging sequence from $S$. Let $q$ be such a point. If $q \in S$, then, clearly, we can take $p_n = q$ for all $n$ and the sequence ${p_n}$ converges to $q$. Suppose therefore that $q$ is in the closure of $S$, and not in $S$. The point $q$ must then be a cluster point for $S$; every neighborhood of $q$ contains points of $S$. Take any convenient decreasing sequence of neighborhoods of $q$, such as the sets
>
> $U_n = \{$all $p$ with $|p-q|<1/n\}$
>
> and choose any point $p_n \in U_n \cap S$. Then, it is evident that $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence in $S$ which converges to $q$.

So, I'm having trouble understanding the following part

> Take any convenient decreasing sequence of neighborhoods of $q$, such as the sets
>
> $U_n = \{$all $p$ with $|p-q|<1/n\}$
>
> and choose any point $p_n \in U_n \cap S$. Then, it is evident that $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence in $S$ which converges to $q$.

Comment: You do not need to get infinitely many $p_n$ in every neighborhood. Instead just pick one point for each $n$. Then the convergent sequence is constructed.

Comment: If that is what you want to ask, then you may edit your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

Because $q$ is in the closure of $S$, then there must exists a point $p_n \in S$ such that $|p_n - q| < \dfrac 1n$. It isn't hard to show that $\lim p_n = q$